# How can I verify in my Dockerfile that PHP contains the modules I need in my image?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I am moving a legacy PHP application running in Apache under Ubuntu 14.04 to Docker for further development.

Therefore I need the PHP engine to have the same modules installed as the Ubuntu install, and I would like to verify automatically in my Dockerfile that the output from `php -m` contains the same modules as a cached output from `php -m` on the Ubuntu machine.

In a shell script I would expect this to be doable using exit codes and `set -e`. The Dockerfile documentation does not mention anything about exit codes from the `RUN` command so it is probably not doable.

So, question is generally "How can I make my Dockerfile build fail from code" but I have asked it specifically for my use case as there might be a smarter way to do it.

Suggestions?

Comment: *The Dockerfile documentation does not mention anything about exit codes from the RUN command so it is probably not doable.* Have you tested it? Any `RUN` not returning `0` would make the build fail actually.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε No I have not tested it.    If not documented and officially supported I am reluctant to rely on it long term.

Comment: Well I would say it is not documented because it is kind of obvious. I am still searching the doc, to see if I can get you something, out of there. But given the fact that exit status of a script are a really standard way of getting feedback on it, it makes all the sense that a build is not successful if any of its command has failed

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I strongly disagree that things that are obvious does not need to be documented.  It only required a single line to document THAT the build can be aborted and what it takes.

Comment: Actually this might not be documented at Docker's level because the API specifications are now coming from a broader specification: https://opencontainers.org/

Answer (score 2):

Although probably not documented, the `RUN` commands are error prone and so, the exit code of a script will make the build fail.

A really naive way to tackle your use case then, would be to have two files and `diff` them.

Here is a skeleton doing this:

```sh
FROM alpine

RUN echo 'a' > a; echo 'a' > b \
    && diff a b 
# all is right, this won't fail

RUN echo 'a' > a; echo 'b' > b \
    && diff a b
# woops?!
```

Would build with:

```
$ docker build .
[+] Building 1.5s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 200B                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                0.6s
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:a75afd8b57e7f34e4dad8d65e2c7ba2e1975c795ce1ee22fa34f8cf4  0.0s
 => [2/3] RUN echo 'a' > a; echo 'a' > b     && diff a b                                                        0.4s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN echo 'a' > a; echo 'b' > b     && diff a b                                                  0.4s
------
 > [3/3] RUN echo 'a' > a; echo 'b' > b     && diff a b:
#6 0.352 --- a
#6 0.352 +++ b
#6 0.352 @@ -1 +1 @@
#6 0.352 -a
#6 0.352 +b
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c echo 'a' > a; echo 'b' > b     && diff a b]: exit code: 1
```

---

So in your real use case what you could do is:

```sh
FROM alpine

COPY php-modules.txt .

RUN php -m | diff php-modules.txt -
```

---

And this is definitely the purposed behaviour:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1875
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2239

Comment: I am fine with running a diff (that was actually what I wanted to do).